# Separating a Queue by every second or third " "

Tags: c#, collections

I'm under the impression that you can't use split to do this from reading around, and so I'm trying to add to the code to split to each and then recombine, but I can't iterate like with an array or list because queues don't keep track of the element number. Please help!

Thanks for the help guys!

```
Queue<string> preWords = new Queue<string>(input.Split(" ".ToCharArray()));
```

// mystery code here to make it combine to pairs?

```
Queue<string> postWords = preWords; 
this.words = postWords;
```

p.s. my original code was as follows:

```
this.words = new Queue<string>(input.Split((" ").ToCharArray()));
```

Comment: Can you give an input and expected output?

Comment: Object[] myStandardArray = mySourceQ.ToArray(); won't work? Then you iterate myStandardArray in a for loop or similar.

Comment: That sounds like something I could try.

I'm sorry forgot a couple of things, first night as a user here.
"this is intended input"
"this is", "intended output"

Comment: Hey, I got it with your toArray help, thanks so much, I'll clean it up a bit tomorrow but the part I couldn't figure out is behind me.

Comment: @gegillam, welcome to SO. The way users post and answer questions can be a bit strict at times. I suggest adding your sample input vs expected output to your original question by clicking `edit`, above. Likewise, you or dwbrito should post the answer as an Answer and then you should mark it as accepted (checkmark).